# Entity framework 6 fails on multi tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework

I have a standard client-server system to use getting entities from server, updating them in client and send back to server to save it (disconnected entity save).
It works good.
But when I try to run the same code using TPL (Task.Run...) I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: An entity object cannot be
>   referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.VerifyContextForAddOrAttach(IEntityWrapper
>   wrappedEntity)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AttachSingleObject(IEntityWrapper
>   wrappedEntity, EntitySet entitySet)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AddEntityToObjectStateManager(IEntityWrapper
>   wrappedEntity, Boolean doAttach)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference.AddEntityToObjectStateManager(IEntityWrapper
>   wrappedEntity, Boolean doAttach)    at...

This is my code in server which I try to run in a different task:

```
using (var dal = UnityManager.Instance.Resolve<IRepositoryDbContextDal>())
{
    dal.Set(entity.GetType()).Attach(entity);
    dal.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    dal.SaveChanges();
}
```

The UnityManager gets me a new class that wrap the DbContext

Comment: what lifetime manager did you specify when registering the IRepositoryDbContextDal?

Comment: the error means that the entity given to the function is used for at least two call. That is the same object (as in Object.ReferenceEquals ) is used for two call with different context.

Comment: I use the defaul life container of Unity which actually gives me new instance each time I resolve

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing is that you are associating entities across multiple active DbContexts. This typically means that you have a DbContext that you think is dead & disposed, but isn't.

As a simple example:

```
Course testCourse = null;
using (var context = new EntityContext())
{
   testCourse = context.Courses.Single(x => x.CourseId == 3);
}
testCourse.Name = "UpdatedTest2";
using (var context = new EntityContext())
{
    context.Courses.Attach(testCourse);
    context.Entry(testCourse).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The above code works. We load an entity with one context, the context is disposed (end of using block) so the entity is now untracked. We can modify it, attach it to another DbContext, set its state to Modified, and save it.

Now take the below code:

```
Course testCourse = null;
var openContext = new EntityContext();
testCourse = openContext.Courses.Single(x => x.CourseId == 3);
testCourse.Name = "UpdatedTest2";

using (var context = new EntityContext())
{
    context.Courses.Attach(testCourse);
    context.Entry(testCourse).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This code is fairly similar, but note that the original context is not disposed. We load the entity and modify it, but then attempt to associate it to another context to save. We get the multiple entity change tracker exception.

The simple fix where you know the Context will not be disposed, and you definitely do need to associate the entity to a second context is to explicitly detach the entity from the original context:

```
Course testCourse = null;
var openContext = new EntityContext();
testCourse = openContext.Courses.Single(x => x.CourseId == 3);
openContext.Entry(testCourse).State = EntityState.Detached; // Remove association from original context.
testCourse.Name = "UpdatedTest2";

using (var context = new EntityContext())
{
    context.Courses.Attach(testCourse);
    context.Entry(testCourse).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

However, in most cases this is merely hiding the underlying problem that you have DbContexts floating around that aren't getting disposed. The key here is to ensure that any DbContexts that are created are disposed. (`using` blocks for any DbContexts that are `new`ed up) If you are using an IoC container then you need to read up on how they assign a lifetime scope to the dependencies they inject.

Comment: As you can see in the attached code, all my uses in the DbContext are disposables.
And this happened only when I try to run this code paralleled with different entities.

Comment: If you're sure the contexts are being disposed, then the issue is that this disposal may not be happening before the entity is fed to another DbContext on a different thread. Whatever code loads the entity needs to detach it from the read DbContext before returning it outside the scope of that Context. `context..Entry(testCourse).State = EntityState.Detached;`  This should ensure that the entity can safely be associated to another context.