# Why is my entity being referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to implement modern practices (using services, IoC, etc.) in my ASP.NET Web Forms project by injecting my DbContext into a service class but I keep getting an error saying `An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.`

This is confusing me because I'm relatively sure I only have a single DbContext tracking changes.

What's the problem? I was using static classes that I sent the DbContext to as function parameters but other than that, I haven't changed anything on the page side...

```
public partial class Create : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private LicenseService licenseService;

    private ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            licenseService = new LicenseService(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // TODO Add error handling/logging.
            ErrorMessage.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
    protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.context.Dispose();
    }

    protected async void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var userManager = Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());

            await SaveLicenseAsync(user);

            // Show a message that the work was done.
            ShowSnackbar("License was successfully added; redirecting...", "Default");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // TODO Add error handling/logging.
            ErrorMessage.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    private async Task SaveLicenseAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        // Get the specified expiry date.
        DateTime.TryParse(ExpiryDatePicker.SelectedDate.ToString(), out DateTime expiryDate);

        // Create the viewmodel that will be passed to the service.
        var model = new LicenseViewModel
        {
            ExpiryDate = expiryDate,
            Name = NameTextBox.Text
        };
        await licenseService.AddAsync(model, user);
    }
}
```

My service generally has all the interaction with EF in it. This I like because it separates the page out of the DbContext logic. I don't like to mix it up. Here's what the service looks like:

public class LicenseService
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext context;
        public LicenseService(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            context = db;
        }

```
    public List<LicenseViewModel> Get()
    {
        var factory = new LicenseViewModelFactory();

        var licenses = context.Licenses.ToList();
        return factory.GetViewModelList(licenses);
    }
    public List<LicenseViewModel> Get(string userId)
    {
        var factory = new LicenseViewModelFactory();

        var licenses = context.Licenses.Where(x => x.User.Id == userId).ToList();
        return factory.GetViewModelList(licenses);
    }
    public LicenseViewModel Get(int licenseId)
    {
        var factory = new LicenseViewModelFactory();
        var license = context.Licenses.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == licenseId);
        return factory.GetViewModel(license);
    }

    public async Task AddAsync(LicenseViewModel model, ApplicationUser owner)
    {
        var license = new License
        {
            ExpiryDate = model.ExpiryDate,
            Name = model.Name,
            User = owner
        };
        context.Licenses.Add(license);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    public async Task AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable<LicenseViewModel> models, ApplicationUser owner)
    {
        var list = new List<License>();
        foreach (var model in models)
        {
            list.Add(new License
            {
                ExpiryDate = model.ExpiryDate,
                Name = model.Name,
                User = owner
            });
        }
        context.Licenses.AddRange(list);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    public async Task UpdateAsync(LicenseViewModel model)
    {
        var license = context.Licenses.Single(x => x.Id == model.Id);
        license.ExpiryDate = model.ExpiryDate;
        license.Name = model.Name;

        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    public async Task DeleteAsync(LicenseViewModel model)
    {
        var license = context.Licenses.Single(x => x.Id == model.Id);
        context.Licenses.Remove(license);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    public async Task DeleteAsync(int licenseId)
    {
        await DeleteAsync(Get(licenseId));
    }
}
```

Comment: "I was using static classes that I sent the DbContext to as function parameters but other than that, I haven't changed anything"  This will be relevant. My guess is your example is trying to simplify the code to what you believe will be relevant but it can be missing critical information that may explain the behaviour. For instance the typo " context.Articles.Add(license);" instead of "...Add(article)" Any advice we can offer will be at best a guess without real code that is exhibiting the problem. Any static class still used with the context would be a good start to look at.

Comment: see my response to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55122962/entity-framework-6-fails-on-multi-tasks/55131117#55131117  for what to look for when facing this error.

Comment: @StevePy I've updated the code with the *actual* code for the page. Literally the only thing I've excluded is the `ShowSnackbar` method which just registers some javascript to display a message on the page. Here's a gist of other code I wrote earlier this week along the same lines which doesn't have this problem... https://gist.github.com/ortund/c0faeca096f8575634fb52ed479cf069

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue will be with your User reference in Licence. That is retrieved from the Owin context, but you are trying to save/associate it with your Licence context.

I'd update the method to simply accept the user ID then load and associate the user from your Licence context.

```
public async Task AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable<LicenseViewModel> models, int ownerId)
{
    var list = new List<License>();
    var owner = context.Users.Single(x => x.UserId == ownerId);
    foreach (var model in models)
    {
        list.Add(new License
        {
            ExpiryDate = model.ExpiryDate,
            Name = model.Name,
            User = owner
        });
    }
    context.Licenses.AddRange(list);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

That should resolve your issue.  Sneaky little detail. :)

To avoid the load you could use:

```
var owner = context.Owners.Local.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserId == ownerId);
if (owner == null)
{
    owner = new User{UserId = ownerId};
    context.Users.Attach(owner);
}
// ...
```

I'd probably consider placing that in a base class method to retrieve an owner reference from the context. The caveat of that approach is that the user from this context will not contain details about the user unless you explicitly load it from the DB. (I.e. Name, etc.) So it's OK from a performance P.o.V. so long as the team knows not to trust that the context will have a complete User unless explicitly reloaded..